# Integral of a function which equals division of its values at integral boundaries

Tags: calculus

I am doing some derivations and stuck at some point.
Given a $C^0$ function $f(x): \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ where $f(x) > 0$ $\forall x$, is it possible to define an integral over an interval $[a,b]$ such that

$$
\int_a^b g[f(x)]\,dx = \frac{f(b)}{f(a)}
$$

where $g$ is a functional of $f$?

If so, what is $g$?

If it makes it easier, the condition could also be

$$
\int_a^b g[f(x)]\,dx = h\left(\frac{f(b)}{f(a)}\right)
$$

where $h$ is an invertible function.

Comment: What do you do when $f(a)=0$?

Comment: In my case, $f(x) > 0 \,\forall x$.

Comment: $a$ and $b$ can very in some interval, I assume?

Comment: $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ if that is what you are asking.

Comment: What I don't understand is why $g(x) = \frac{f(b)}{(b-a)f(a)}$ for $x \in \mathbb R$ isn't a solution. Or do you want to find a function $g: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ (so you have to determine $g(x)$ for each $x$ by itself, rather than a functional $g: C^0 \to C^?$ that allows you to determine $g(f)$ knowing all of $f$ (as I did above).

Comment: This is an intermediate step in another computation. Let's say for now that $a$ and $b$ are not chosen, but computed from another function.

The reason a posted the question is that I had a hunch there is an integral involving $f$'s derivative, but didn't know how to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a well defined and bounded function independent from $f(x)$ and the bounds of integral $a,b$ does not exist because otherwise we should have $$\int_a^ag[f(x)]dx=0$$and while $\int_a^ag[f(x)]dx={f(a)\over f(x)}=1$ we must have $$0=1$$ which is a contradiction. Therefore such $g$ doesn't exist.